# meta.touched is not getting true on form submit in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-final-form, final-form

I have gone through a similar problem but that did not resolve my issue.
I am working on a React app and React final form, According to the react final form developer the meta.touched will be true on form submit.

I tried the same, but the issue still persists.

I am generating the field data dynamically from the backend and render them in UI.

**My Code**

```
<Form
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
                // validate={validate}
                initialValues={ocaFormUserInput}
                subscription={{ submitting: true }}
                render={({ handleSubmit, submitting }) => (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                      <Grid container>
                                            {formFieldDatum?.blockFields &&
                                                formFieldDatum?.blockFields.length !== 0 &&
                                                formFieldDatum?.blockFields.map((blockField, index) => (
                                                    <Grid className={classes.formGrid} item sm={6} xs={12} key={index}>
                                                        {blockField.jsonFeild.map((field, fieldKey) => {
                                                            return <AllInputFields key={fieldKey} field={field} setInvalid={setInvalid} />;
                                                        })}
                                                    </Grid>
                                                ))}
                                        </Grid>
                       <div className={classes.buttonBox}>
                            <Button className={classes.cancelBtn} onClick={prevFormProgress} variant="outlined" disabled={activeStep === 0}>
                                PREVIOUS
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                                className={classes.nextBtn}
                                onSubmit={!invalid ? handleActiveStep : undefined}
                                type="submit"
                                disabled={activeStep === 4 && submitting}
                                variant="contained"
                            >
                                {activeStep < 4 ? "NEXT" : "SUBMIT"}
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

AllInputFields component

```
if (inputField.fieldDisplayTypeName === "TextField") {
        return (
            <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
                <Field
                    name={inputField.name}
                    validate={inputField.isMandatory && required}
                    type="text"
                    fieldProp={inputField}
                    subscription={{
                        value: true,
                        touched: true,
                        error: true,
                    }}
                >
                    {({ input, meta, fieldProp }) => (
                        <>
                            <TextField
                                {...input}
                                className={classes.textField}
                                variant="outlined"
                                label={fieldProp.label}
                                placeholder={fieldProp.placeholder}
                                required={fieldProp.isMandatory}
                                InputLabelProps={{
                                    shrink: true,
                                }}
                                error={meta.touched && meta.error}
                                helperText={meta.touched && meta.error && meta.error}
                                InputProps={{
                                    readOnly: activeStep === reviewTabIndex,
                                    autoComplete: "off",
                                }}
                            />
                            {fieldProp.isMandatory ? (meta.error ? setInvalid(true) : setInvalid(false)) : undefined}
                            <pre>{JSON.stringify(meta, 0, 2)}</pre>
                        </>
                    )}
                </Field>
            </FormControl>
        );
    }
```

I am using MUI theme for the design.

Kindly suggest me solution to get way out.
I am trying to find solution but could not find one.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!dirty) {
  const fields = form.getRegisteredFields()
  
  fields.map((field) => {
    form.focus(field);
    form.blur(field);
  });
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.

Answer (score -2):

I got the perfect solution for the issue....
**react-hook-form**. If you are starting a project then use react-hook-form, it is much better than react final form and has a great community.

React Hook Form >>> React Final Form

Comment: Suggesting another package isn't really answering the question.

FWIW, the solution here appears to be that you need to add `onBlur={event => input.onBlur(event)}` to your `<TextField />`

Comment: @JosephShambrook That I have tried even that did not work